# Error al conectar SQL CLoud con APP Engine

Tags: python, sql, flask

Tengo mi aplicación Python/Flask/Mysql. La subí a Google Cloud y funciona perfecto python y flask, pero al conectarlo a mi base de datos que la tengo en SQL Cloud en el mismo proyecto, ocurren 3 errores.
He seguido el [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine?hl=es_419#setting_up_a_instance) al pie de la letra, pero me devuelve 3 errores:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory 

OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 2] No such file or directory)") 

OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 2] No such file or directory)")
```

Mi código para conectarme es:

```
    #CONEXIÓN A SQL CLOUD
db_user = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
db_pass = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
db_name = "my_database"
cloud_sql_connection_name = "xxxxxxxxxx "

app=Flask(__name__)

db = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    # Equivalent URL:
    # mysql+pymysql://<db_user>:<db_pass>@/<db_name>?unix_socket=/cloudsql/<cloud_sql_instance_name>
    sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
        drivername="mysql+pymysql",
        username=db_user,
        password=db_pass,
        database=db_name,
        query={"unix_socket": "/cloudsql/{}".format(cloud_sql_connection_name)}, 
    ))
#CONEXIÓN A SQL CLOUD
```

Y mis consultas las hago dentro de cada función:

```
    @app.route('/demo')
        def demo():
            global db
            with db.connect() as conn:
                fetched_all_sm = conn.execute(
                "SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY precio_ml ASC"
                ).fetchall()

    return render_template('demo.html', fetched_all_sm=fetched_all_sm)
```

Espero puedan ayudarme de alguna forma. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Ya revisaste que el nombre de la variable `cloud_sql_connection_name` sea el adecuado? ¿Revisaste las diagonales, etc?